# Finding the Intersect of 'n' Generic Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, generics, intersection

**EDIT :** Added far more detail.

I'm trying to write an algorithm that finds the intersection (points common to all) of n arrays. My program takes these arrays and stores them in a two dimensional array on which the operations take place. For example, here is a sample main method:

```
int a[] = { 12, 54, 42 };
int b[] = { 54, 3, 42, 7 };
int c[] = { 3, 42, 54, 57, 3 };

IntersectionTableau<int> x(3);    // Where 3 is the max number of arrays allowed
                                  // to be stored.
x.addArray(a, 3);
x.addArray(b, 4);
x.addArray(c, 9);
x.run();            // Finds the intersection.
```

These added arrays will be stored in `T** arrays` and their sizes in `int* sizes`. T is a generic type. What is an efficient algorithm that will let me do this on a variable number of arrays of generic types?

Here is what I'm currently attempting to do:

```
template <class T>
inline
void IntersectionTableau<T>::run() {
    T* commonElements = d_arrays[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < d_currentNumberOfArrays; ++i) {
        commonElements = getIntersection(commonElements, d_arrays[i], d_sizes[i - 1], d_sizes[i]);
    }
    d_results = commonElements;
}



template <class T>
inline
T* IntersectionTableau<T>::getIntersection(T* first, T* second, int sizeOfFirst, int sizeOfSecond) {
    T* commonElements;
    if (sizeOfFirst > sizeOfSecond) {
        commonElements = new T[sizeOfFirst];
    } else {
        commonElements = new T[sizeOfSecond];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfFirst; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfSecond; ++j) {
            if (first[i] == second[i]) {
                commonElements[i] = first[i];
            }
        }
    }
return commonElements;
```

}

The first function takes the first two arrays and sends them to the second function, which returns an array of the intersections between those two arrays. Then, the first function compares the intersection array with the next array in `d_arrays` and so on. My problem is when I go to print out an element from `d_results` a garbage value is produced, and I'm unsure why. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or alternatively, a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems in the code:

---

```
if (first[i] == second[i])
```

This should be `if (first[i] == second[j])`.

---

```
commonElements[i] = first[i];
```

This is trickier to fix. I think you want to have another variable (neither `i` nor `j`); let's call it `k`:

```
commonElements[k++] = first[i];
```

---

Anyway, since you can use C++, you can use a `std::vector` instead. It stores its size inside; this will reduce confusion:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> // note: adjusted the return type!
IntersectionTableau<T>::getIntersection(...)
{
    std::vector<T> commonElements;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfFirst; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfSecond; ++j) {
            if (first[i] == second[j]) {
                commonElements.push_back(first[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements;
}
```

You can turn `first` and `second` into vectors too (though you won't benefit much from it right now).

Here are some points to note:

- I changed the return type to `vector<T>`
- The old version, which returns an array, requires additional code to specify the length of its result; this version returns the length inside the `vector<T>` object
- The old version, which returns an array, requires `delete[] array` somewhere later, to prevent a memory leak
- The `vector`-to-pointer hack `&commonElements[0]` will not work for an empty `vector`

If your other code works with an array/pointer, you can use the `vector`-to-pointer hack `&commonElements[0]`, but *outside* the function, in order to respect the lifetime rules:

```
T* commonElements = NULL;
for (int whatever = 0; whatever < 10; ++whatever)
{
    std::vector<T> elements = xxx.getIntersection(...); // will work
    commonElements = &elements[0]; // can pass this pointer to a function receiving T*
    print(commonElements); // will work
}
print(commonElements); // cannot possibly work, will probably segfault
print(elements); // cannot possibly work, and compiler will reject this
```

Comment: (first[i] == second[i]), can't believe I missed that! Besides that, if I were to use vector, would I be able to cast that as type `T*` for the purposes of returning it? I'm unfamiliar with `std::vector`. Good response though, it helped quite a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, so I'm using your `std::vector` method, which appears to work (the program builds correctly), however, when returning using the statement `return &commonElements[0]` the program produces a segfault. This doesn't happen when I use my code, save for the correction `if (first[i] == second[j])`. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: it segfaults because you are returning address of a local object, which will be deleted after returning from function.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this (return a vector as an array) without having it be deleted?